# C# Possible method to call protected non-static methods in current class?

Tags: c#, methods

I've recently picked up C# as another language to further my knowledge into other languages, but as experimenting to get used to the syntax of the language, I encountered this problem when using the `public static void Main();` and calling methods inside the same class. My code was as follows:

```
namespace TestingProject
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("This is nothing but a test \n Input 'test'");
            var UserInput = System.Console.ReadLine();
            string Input = this.ValidateInput(UserInput);
            System.Console.WriteLine(Input);
            System.Console.WriteLine();

        }
        protected string ValidateInput(string Variable)
        {
            var VarReturn = (string)null;
            if (string.Equals(Variable, "test"))
            {
                VarReturn = "Correct \n";
            }
            else
            {
                VarReturn = "Incorrect \n";
            }
            return VarReturn;
        }


    }
}
```

So, from what i've researched it turns out that you cannot use the `this` syntax to call internal private methods from a static function.

So I tried `self` but this returned no avail (assuming since languages such as python, PHP allow `self`), so tried the following:

```
string Input = TestingProject.Class1.ValidateInput(UserInput);
```

To be presented with the following message:

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'TestingProject.Class1.ValidateInput(string)' C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\ClassProject\Class1.cs   14  28  ClassProject

So then, I found this little gem which did solve the problem :

```
var CurrClass = new Class1();
```

and called the protected method as so:

```
var CurrClass = new Class1();
string Input = CurrClass.ValidateInput(UserInput);
```

Which did surprise me that this was the only available way to call internal non-staic private methods, so my overall question is:

Is there a way to call non-static methods which are protected/private without initializing a new variable to contain the current object?

Comment: "Non-static method" is another way of saying "instance method", i.e., a method that only works with/on an object of the class it is defined in. That mean, you will need an object of that class to call an instance method. That is the concept of instance methods. If you want to a method being callable without having an existing object, don't make it an "instance method", but make it a static method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Main` method is static. A static method can not access non-static methods, even within the same class, without having an instance of the object. That is the entire point of having a static method: you don't have a concrete object to work with. It's outside of the scope of the other instance methods.

Comment: So even with methods being present in the same class, non-static and static work on completely different scopes and are unable to communicate one another without an essential "child" object being created to handle the calls?

Comment: @DarylGill, not exactly. You can always call a static method from an instance method (assuming method access modifers such as public/protected/internal allow it). But you cannot call an instance method from a static method without having an object of the class that provides the instance method (as you noticed...)

Comment: I'm completely following, logic of this language is a major change from the less maintained/strict languages which I was based in. Thank you for the information